# How to run an initializer that calls Rails.application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've seen posts where the suggestion was to create an initializer or create a `config.after_initialize` block in the `config/application.rb` file; however, this doesn't properly work for me because I'm relying on Rails credentials.

For example, I have a class called `SlackBot` that basically sends a message to our slack channel. I'd like to create an initializer that sends a message once the `rails s` command is run, but the `config.after_initialize` doesn't actually work since the `SlackBot` class pulls creds from `Rails.application.credentials`

I get the following error when trying to do this:

```
ubuntu@bf29b8edfeea:~/myapp$ rails s --binding 0.0.0.0 -p 80                                                                                                                                       
=> Booting Puma                                                                                                                                                                                    
=> Rails 6.1.4.4 application starting in development                                                                                                                                               
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options                                                                 
Exiting                                                                                                                                              
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.4/lib/active_support/message_verifier.rb:176:in `verify': ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature (ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignat
ure)                                                                                                                                        
        from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.4/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:154:in `decrypt_and_verify'
        from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.4/lib/active_support/messages/rotator.rb:22:in `decrypt_and_verify'
        from /home/ubuntu/myapp/app/helpers/user_helper.rb:19:in `decrypt_data'
```

The only way I can get rid of this error of course is by removing the custom initializer.

Is there a way that I can call an initializer or method *after* rails is fully initializer, perhaps as the last step that runs?

Comment: can you add a "require" to your initializer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [The Rails Initialization Process](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html) of the Rails official reference, the last file to be executed in the initialization sequence is `config/environment.rb` (Note that although the reference states the last one is `config/application.rb`, the file should have been in default *require*-d in the earlier process).

In Rails 6 (or maybe earlier ones, too?), the last line in `config/environment.rb` is

```rb
Rails.application.initialize!
```

So, if you write your own statements after the line in the file `config/environment.rb`, your Rails app must have been fully initialized by the time your statements are executed.

Comment: Nice. This did the trick perfectly. Just placed it right afterwards. Thanks!

Comment: ive been searching the past couple days for how to do this. you're a life saver. Thanks!